# Accessing instance methods that are two objects deep in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Say I have a class, `Bobject` with an instance variable and method to retrieve it:

```
public class Bobject {
    private int bInstVar;

    public Bobject() {
        bInstVar = 1;
    }

    getBInstVar() {
        return bInstVar;
    } 
}
```

If I create a class `Cobject` representing an object that is an array of `Bobject` like so:

```
public class Cobject {
    public Bobject[] cInstVar;

    public Cobject() {
        cInstVar = new Bobject[2]; //arbitrary array size for simplicity of the question
        for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++;) {
            cInstVar[i] = new Bobject(); 
        }
    }
}
```

If I have a main program that creates a `Cobject` and attempts to access methods of the references to the `Bobjects` stored in each element, I find that I have to first access the `Cobject` instance variable, `cInstVar`. This means cInstVar has to be `public` for main() to get at it without a method if main is outside of the package or class.

My question is, is there a way around doing this:?

```
Cobject c = new Cobject;
    c.cObject1[0].getBInstVar();
```

Instead, I want to have an object that is an array of another class and get to that classes instance methods easier like so:

```
Cobject c = new Cobject;
    c.getBInstVar(); // error says 'array required, but Cobject found'
```

I'm still pretty new to Java (and stackExchange) so please forgive me if anything I've presented is unclear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want a `Cobject` like `c` to have a `getBInstVar` method, the best approach would be to add a `getBInstvar` method to `Cobject`.  It's pretty easy to do.  Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb class variable should be declared as private and you should use getter and settle methods....

Meaning you will need to create a getter method in 'Cobject' to get the 'Bobject' object your after.... Then another getter/setter method to access any attributes there, or a method to manipulate any data

But yes, you could hard code a method that will go into the array and return what you ask for. Probably need an index parameter tho

Comment: Thank you! This answer solved my issue and was very helpful. I did end up using a parameter for the array index in the `Cobject` getter method.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a getter method for Bobject[] in Cobject class 
and then you can do c.getCObject1()[0].getBInstVar();